# Flutter text fields and keyboard avoidance

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having trouble understanding the keyboard avoidance dynamic.

Could anyone explain the behavior shown in this example below?

I think ultimately, I would like the whole screen to be scrollable, rather than removing the expandable space when the virtual keyboard pops up. (for example, the spacing between "Log in" and the text fields)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to false in your `Scaffold`.

Comment: When I set resizeToAvoidBottominset to false, the keyboard covers the text fields, which make sense because we are not resizing now. I suppose I am wondering how I might be able to make the entire screen scrollable and avoid the keyboard, while keeping the focused text field in the middle of the screen

Comment: Well if you want the whole screen to be scrollable you can just use a singlechildscrollview with ClampingScrollPhysics.

Comment: You'll want to set resizeToAvoidBottomInset to false and then use either a ListView or SingleChildScrollView (either will work...and remove the Flexible/Expanded widgets). There is a scrollPadding parameter you can add to your TextField to make the field automatically scroll up when the keyboard is opened. You can achieve: 1) No page scrolling when the keyboard is closed, and 2) Automatic scrolling when the keyboard opens.

Comment: please add your code snippet for better solutions...

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you have to warp your widgets with `SingleChildScrollView`, I've made an example to explain in detail how to implement it. You can try it with your code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            children: List.generate(
          6,
          (index) => const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Example',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The above code result would outpot:
[image: Code Outpot]

Comment: Must i use SingleChildScrollView? What if i'm using CustomScrollView as the parent widget. The textfield still hides behind the keyboard.

Comment: @Brendan in my example it doesn't hide. and it's preferable to use SingleChildScrollView. try warp the CustomScrollView with it.

Comment: Wrapping the CustomScrollView with SingleChildScrollView causes an Overflow. `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.`yaml

Comment: Have you tried this on your end?