# Flutter SingleChildScrollView Not Working

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I want the scroll page to work when the keyboard is opened, but it does not work when the keyboard is opened, the user needs to see what he is typing, I am making a login page, when the keyboard opens, the scrollview will work, I used the same code in my other project, but it works there, it just does not work in my project, what could be the reason for this?
Edit: What I want to do is, when the keyboard pops up, I should be able to scroll the screen

My Code:

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: scrollController,
              child: Container(
                padding: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > webScreenSize
                    ? EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3)
                    : const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 15,
                      ),
                height: deviceHeight,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        "assets/bahce.svg",
                        color: primaryColor,
                        height: 64.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: deviceHeight * 0.65,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: LayoutBuilder(
                        builder: (ctx, contsraints) {
                          return Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: contsraints.maxHeight * 0.01,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                .......
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: contsraints.maxHeight * 0.05,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: contsraints.maxHeight * 0.12,
                               ...................
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: contsraints.maxHeight * 0.12,
                               ......button
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: contsraints.maxHeight * 0.15,
                              ),
                              RichText(
                                text: TextSpan(
                                  ......,
                                  children: [
                                    TextSpan(
                                      
                                        ..onTap = navigateToSignup,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. Your code is also not something we can use to try to reproduce your issue. Check this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check this answer because is the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/72128966/8820842

Comment: is the issue solved or need help ?

Comment: I'm not sure, haven't tried just yet, but maybe it has something to do with your layout builder being under your single child scroll view, try and exchange them

Answer (score 0):

Remove other widgers directly use sigle child scroll view as a child of body